# Possible race condition while processing a Queue in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, queue

I have an array of properties that are children of an object that will need to be persisted via AJAX calls to a database. However, the way the API is working right now (this is highly unlikely to change) I cannot send the strings in a batch and if I send them using a simple loop they will each overwrite each other. So I need to process additions and subtractions as a FIFO queue.

I'm just trying to verify if my thinking is correct in that processing the AJAX call back interrupts processing of the actions that add/subtract properties to the queue.

Code (using jQuery $.ajax for shorthand):

```
var queue = [],
    processing = false;

function processQueue() {
    if(queue.length <= 0) {
        processing = false;
        return;
    }

    if(processing) {
        return;
    }

    processing = true;
    var cmd = queue.unshift();

    $.post(cmd.location, cmd.payload, function handleSuccess() {
        processing = false;
        processQueue();
    });
}

function addToQueue(url, payload) {
    queue.push({ location: url, payload: payload });
    processQueue();
}
```

Primarily I'm concerned about which `processQueue();` call gets made first after the initial one. Assuming that I've added several things to the queue and then called `processQueue();`. I believe that if a call to `handleSuccess();` is made in the middle of a call to `addToQueue()` that the call to `processQueue()` from `addToQueue()` would result in an early return since `processing == true`. However, I'm not certain enough of this.

Am I correct in my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> processing the AJAX call back interrupts processing of the actions that add/subtract properties to the queue.

No. JavaScript is singlethreaded, no race conditions can occur in synchronous code. The ajax callback is queued in the event queue, and will get scheduled to be executed after any currently-executing code.